# Preprocessor flag to detect CGO build?

Tags: go, cgo

In a c file that's beside my go file and is compiled together via CGO, I'd like to check via preprocessor whether it's being compiled via go or not. I'd like to do this because, for example, I'd like to protect `#include _cgo_export.h` with `#ifdef` flags, since such header exists solely during compilation and I don't want my editor to warn about its absence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) just do:

```
// #cgo CFLAGS: -DWHATEVER_YOU_WANT_TO_INDICATE_CGO=1
import "C"
```

(or just `-D FOO` if you don't want a value) or set `CGO_CFLAGS` in the environment.

You can see what is happening behind the scenes with `go build -x`.
For me it shows `-D GOOS_freebsd -D GOARCH_amd64` while compiling the cgo generated `_cgo_defun.c` file, but *only* for that file and **not** to my own *.c files. So I don't think there are any usable predefined preprocessor flags (and the documentation also doesn't mention any).

Comment: I'm not sure, but for your specific use case `// #include "_cgo_export.h"` immediately before the `import "C"` might also work.